# OnChangeTrigger does not run and have an error message in the GAS trigger panel

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I don't understand why my trigger does not run correctly.

I wrote this script to automatically log all changes performed in this spreadsheet. These logs would be written in the sheet "Management Sheet" in the range "D4:H". The fields which must be filled in this range will be: [1--> user email ,2--> new Date(),"--> changeType,4--> sheetName,5--> range of modification)]

```
function setUpTrigger(){
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('loggerModifFunction')
  .forSpreadsheet('ss Id')
  .onChange()
  .create();
}

function loggerModifFunction(e) {
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Management Sheet').getRange(e.range.getLastRow(), 5).setValue([user,new Date(),changeType,sheetName,range]);
}
```

Google script window shows the following error:

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'lastRow'of undefined".

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `e.range.getLastRow()` is not the only error. Take a look on `getRange(row,column,nb of rows, nb of columns)` and setValue() versus setValues()

Comment: @MikeSteelson consider to use `appendRow` instead of `setValues`.

Comment: ok thx for the advice Rubén

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
function loggerModifFunction(e) {
  Browser.msgBox(JSON.stringify(e))
}
```

this will show you what information is available!

```
{"authMode":"FULL","changeType":"EDIT","source":{},"triggerUid":"123456789012345","user":{"email":"XXX@gmail.com","nickname":"XXXX"}}
```

In any case you can fetch `e.range` neither `user` or `changeType`

You can fetch for instance `e.user.email`, or `e.changeType`

### Code #1

```
function setUpTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('loggerModifFunction')
    .forSpreadsheet('ssID1')
    .onChange()
    .create();
}

function loggerModifFunction(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ssID2')
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Management Sheet')
  sh.appendRow([e.user.nickname, new Date(), e.changeType, e.source.getActiveSheet().getName(), e.source.getActiveRange().getA1Notation()])
}
```

where

- ssID1 : the ID of the spreadsheet I want to survey
- ssID2 : the ID of the spreadsheet I want to collect and write the changes (the code is built in this spreadsheet)

### Code #2

If you want a specific location and exclude some sheets

```
function loggerModifFunction(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1HlRT30uvpPD7GNrv2aRZydO1a3zc0kQOulGBd_0mc3k')
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Management Sheet')
  var sheetName = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName()
  var excl = ['Sheet1','Sheet2'];//excluded sheets
  if (excl.indexOf(sheetName) == -1){
    sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1,4,1,5).setValues([[e.user.nickname, new Date(), e.changeType, sheetName, e.source.getActiveRange().getA1Notation()]])}
}
```

### Nota

If your are not in the same organization, due to permission policy you will not be able to recover user (except yourself)

Comment: Hi Mike, Thank you Mike ! As you know, my knowledge in script language is very limited. I've tried to do something with yours recommandations but I don't find the solution !

Comment: tell us what you want to do

Comment: I would like to log automatically all changes performed in this spreadsheet. These logs would be written in the sheet "Management Sheet" in the range "D4:H". The fields which must be filled in this range will be: [1--> user email ,2--> new Date(),"--> changeType,4--> sheetName,5--> range of modification)]

Comment: done, try it with your own spreadsheets!

Comment: Thank you very much. it runs and the log appears. But 2 elements need to be improved, which I have not been able to do. 1- make the log appear on the range D4:H4
2-how to exclude a sheet from the results of the logs (exclude Management sheet)?

Comment: Thank you for your help and appeciated disponibility ! Regards

Comment: If everything is ok, pls acept the answer. See you soon for other opportunities.

Answer (score 0):

#### range is not in the event object

Code to get event object:

```
function onMyChange(e) {
  JSON.stringify(e));
}
```

event object:

```
"authMode":"","changeType":"","source":{},"triggerUid":"","user":{"email":"","nickname":""}}
```